# Page Loading Animation Stops Animating Long Before Page Loading on IOS Devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I`m using page loading animation in our project. Its been animating by a javascript library called Sprite Animate. It animates a sprite sheet and uses canvas. It works pretty well on desktop browsers and Android devices. However, in IOS devices animation freezes long before page loading and when the new page starts loading, animation disappears very early.
It should keep appear and animate until new page loads and should disappear just before the new page loaded as in Android devices and desktop browsers. 
Both Android and Ios video samples given below. 
**Android Page Loading Animation Example**
https://youtu.be/s2LBIeTvz60 
**IOS Page Loading Animation Example** 
https://youtu.be/waowCrDWbbM

I tried to change the animation configuration but nothing changed.
I removed current animation, disabled sprite animation js library and put a gif animation instead of the current animation. I get the same results and gif animation stopped in Ios devices like sample videos above.

After that, I compared Android and Ios devices` page animation display behaviors in any other web site (especially the web sites that have slightly longer form submission response). What I realized is animations freeze and disappear earlier in Ios devices.

Can anyone explain why does this pattern happens in Ios devices? Is there any difference between Ios devices and other devices in page loading? Where can I search for this difference and get knowledge about it?

The code behind page loading animation in our project is given below.

In Html files, there is a loading element

```
<div id="loader" class="loading" style="display: none">
 <img id="imgLogo" hidden="true"th:src="@{...../loading.png}"/>
 <canvas id="spinner"></canvas>
</div>
```

animation configuration js file. Show hide methods basically change the loader elements Css style and make it appear/disappear

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import "./sprite-animate";

const SHOW_TIMEOUT = 200;
let loader;
let timer;
let loaderCount = 0;

$(document).ready(() => {
    var $canvas = $('#spinner');
    var absPath = $('#imgLogo').prop('src');
    $canvas.spriteAnimate({
        frameWidth: 300,
        frameHeight: 300,
        numberOfFrames: 50,
        imgSrc: absPath,
        fps: 40,
        loop: true
    });
    $canvas.spriteAnimate('play');
    loader = document.getElementById('loader');
    loaderCount = 0;
});

export const show = () => {
    if (!loader)
        return;
    loaderCount++;
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        loader.style.display = '';
    }, SHOW_TIMEOUT);
};

export const hide = () => {
    if (!loader)
        return;
    if(loaderCount!==0){
        loaderCount--;
    }
    if (loaderCount === 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        loader.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

Whenever form submitted, loader animation appears and after form action completed it`s been hidden.

```
export default function basket() {
    let formSubmitState = false;

    $(document).find("form").one('submit', function (e) {
        loader.show();
    });

    $(document).find("form").bind('ajax:complete', function () {
        loader.hide();
    });
}
```